# Mark iOS app as NOT compatible with ios6

Tags: iphone, app-store, compatibility

I have an iPhone app that's working on iOS 5, but has serious, non-trivial problems with iOS 6. Is there a way to mark the app as incompatible with iOS 6 for a little while in the App Store, so that users with iOS 6 would not see it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make it invisible to the `iOS` 6 users. Only thing you can do is, in app launch check what is the current OS and show a message to the User and quit the app. But I wont recommend doing that. The better solution is to fix the issues in `iOS` 6 and release the app. That would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, I don't think so. Of the two iOS versions, obviously iOS6 will be supported longer into the future than iOS5. Whatever your app's issues are under iOS6, clearly you need to fix them. If anything, if you have to drop iOS5 support in order to make it work to your liking under iOS6, then I say: so be it. (I'd call this a last resort, but legitimate if you have no other choice.) Eventually, all your iOS5 users will be on iOS6 and beyond anyway. As a data point, the number of iOS4 users has dwindled dramatically already.